# How to remove black bars from vlcj canvas and extend canvas to two GridBagLayout rows?

Tags: java, canvas, gridbaglayout, vlcj

I have black bars surrounding my video player, as shown in the figure below. How do I get rid of them? I tried fixing the sizes in the AVPlayer class but while that stopped the random resizing of the video player, it didn't get rid of the black bars.

My second question: how do make it so that the video player sits where it is now, but moves up a bit so that the top of the player is on the same row as the combobox? Right now it is on the same row as the JLabel displaying "English" but I want it to extend on both rows.

[image]

Below you will find my SSCCE. It is still a bit long but I got rid of all the dependencies. You should get the image above if you compile it. I put the AVPlayer class as an inner class to simplify the code, it actually has its own class. You will need to add a video source for the video player to show up.

```
public class SSCCE extends JPanel {

private final JLabel kanjiLabel;
private final JLabel englishLabel;
private final JPanel wordPanel, cbPanel;
private final JComboBox chapters;
private final DefaultComboBoxModel model;
private final JLabel chapLabel = new JLabel("Chapter");
private AVPlayer player;

private final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

public SSCCE() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setConstraints();

    //wordPanel
    wordPanel = new JPanel();
    wordPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(wordPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    wordPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 150));

    kanjiLabel = new JLabel();
    englishLabel = new JLabel();

    kanjiLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 50));
    englishLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 40));

    wordPanel.add(englishLabel);
    wordPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));
    wordPanel.add(kanjiLabel);

    //chapter combox
    chapters = new JComboBox();
    model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    chapters.setModel(model);
    cbPanel = new JPanel();
    addCB();

    constraints.gridy += 1;
    add(wordPanel, constraints);
    //add the audio video panel
    player = new AVPlayer();
    constraints.gridx += 1;
    add(player, constraints);
}

private void setConstraints() {
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.weightx = 1.0;
    constraints.weighty = 0.0;
}

private void addCB() {
    setConstraints();
    cbPanel.removeAll();
    cbPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
    cbPanel.add(chapLabel);
    cbPanel.add(chapters);
    add(cbPanel, constraints);

}

public void displayNewWord() {

    kanjiLabel.setText("Kanji");
    englishLabel.setText("English");
    player.playVideo("video.mp4"); //replace this with a video on your computer
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public class AVPlayer extends JPanel {

    private static final String VLCPATH = "C:\\VideoLAN\\VLC";

    private final MediaPlayerFactory mpf;
    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp;

    public AVPlayer() {

        //this panels sizes
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

        //canvas
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

        add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //load the native vlc library
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), VLCPATH);
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();

        emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(canvas));

    }

    public void playVideo(String path) {
        emp.prepareMedia(path);
        emp.play();
        emp.setRepeat(true);
    }
}
}
```

And the main method

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    SSCCE sscce = new SSCCE();
    frame.add(sscce, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    sscce.displayNewWord();
    frame.revalidate();
```

Comment: It's better not to ask two different questions in the same post, and instead post them as separate questions. Your second question is not related to vlcj and is a more general Swing question. I added an answer here for the first question you asked (about vlcj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black bars are part of the video output from the embedded VLC media player.

You need to set appropriate aspect ratio and/or crop geometry to get rid of them.

For example:

```
mediaPlayer.setCropGeometry("4:3");         // W:H
mediaPlayer.setCropGeometry("719x575+0+0"); // WxH+L+T
mediaPlayer.setCropGeometry("6+10+6+10");   // L+T+R+B
mediaPlayer.setAspectRatio("185:100");
```

Only you know what the correct values should be.

Alternatively, if the black bars are not in the native video output, then this is caused by the your `Canvas` size not having the same aspect ratio as the video.

You can work out which of the two issues you're having by setting your `Canvas` background to some other colour.

Comment: So that's what's happening. I thought it it was happening because the JPanel and canvas weren't sized properly. Thanks for giving me these methods, I should be able to figure things out from here by experimenting.